# React Router doesn't match

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am learning React Router. The following is a problem when I use Route.

```js
const OPSTIONS = [
 {
  name: "home",
  path: "/",
  main: () => <h1>Home</h1>,
  sidebar: () => <h1>Home</h1>
 },
 {
  name: "mike",
  path: "/mike",
  main: () => <h2>mike</h2>,
  sidebar: () => <h3>mike</h3>
 },
 {
  name: "jerry",
  path: "/jerry",
  main: () => <h2>jerry</h2>,
  sidebar: () => <h3>jerry</h3>
 },
 {
  name: "jim",
  path: "/jim",
  main: () => <h2>jim</h2>,
  sidebar: () => <h3>jim</h3>
 },
]

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <div>
   <ul>
    {OPSTIONS.map(function(e, index) {
     return <li key={index}><Link to={e.path}>{e.name}</Link></li>
    })}
   </ul>
  </div>
 </Router>,
 document.getElementById("left")
);

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <div>
   {OPSTIONS.map(function(e, index) {
    return <Route exact key={index} path={e.path} component={e.main}></Route>
   })}
  </div>
 </Router>,
 document.getElementById("main")
)
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl2wr.png)

And the Router always match the Home Route, no matter what I change the url, the component always show "Home", did I make something wrong? How can I fix it?

And this is my react and react-router version:

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  }
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I am using react v15.6.1 and react-router v4.2.0 and react-router-dom v4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Switch` to wrap it all your `Route` to only render first matched component.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        {OPSTIONS.map(function(e, index) {
            return <Route exact key={index} path={e.path} component={e.main}></Route>
        })}
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

You can read more about it in https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: I have used <Switch> to wraps it, and it doesn't work too